# I want to create an escrow program in Rust on Solana

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js

I need help to create ESCROW in Rust

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need to understand the escrow flow in Rust on Solana](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7574/i-need-to-understand-the-escrow-flow-in-rust-on-solana)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some code that you will need :

1. you will need to create a vault account, it will holds the sol + information about who sent this sol, and how much sol (this account is a PDA)

   #[account]
   pub struct LockAccount {
   pub buyer: Pubkey,
   pub amount: u64,
   }
2. when transfering the SOL, you need to create this account, like this :

   #[derive(Accounts)]
   #[instruction(amount: u64)]
   pub struct SendSol<'info> {

   #[account(mut, signer)]
   /// CHECK
   pub buyer: AccountInfo<'info>,

   /// CHECK
   pub vault_authority: AccountInfo<'info>,

   /// CHECK
   #[account(
   init,
   payer = buyer,
   seeds = [...],
   space=32 + 32 + 32,
   bump,
   )]
   pub vault_account: Account<'info, LockAccount>,
   ...
   }

In your SendSol function, you need :

- To input the data in the vault account
- To transfer the sols

Inputing the data :

```
ctx.accounts.vault_account.buyer = *ctx.accounts.buyer.key;
    ctx.accounts.vault_account.amount = amount;
```

Sending the SOL :

```
let ix = anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
        &ctx.accounts.buyer.to_account_info().key(),
        &ctx.accounts.vault_account.to_account_info().key(),
        price,
    );

    anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke(
        &ix,
        &[
        ctx.accounts.buyer.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.vault_account.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ],
```

in your cancel function, you can use this kind of code to retrieve the sols:

```
**ctx.accounts.vault_account.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= ctx.accounts.vault_account.amount;
    **ctx.accounts.buyer.to_account_info().try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += ctx.accounts.vault_account.amount;
```

For the other piece of code, i think you can find them in the tutorials.

If you're stuck at a specific part of your process, please ask a question, i will reply ;)

PS : i don't know why formatting is nor working for the first pieces of code, i let you format them as you wish ;)

PS2 : you have to understand what a PDA (program derived address) is, it will help you understand what you are doing

In the tuto you will also find an escrow account, which holds data, but i'm pretty sure you can put them in the lock account and you don't need an additional escrow account (as long as you have 1 vault per buyer / transaction, without using an escrow account, you can't sum multiple ticket bought from the same buyer)

PS3 : for the seeds in my example, you have to use relevant stuff, like buyer wallet address, lotery ID for example

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this. Hopefully this will help me a lot for clearing.

Comment: please if it did help, accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was changing some flow.
Now I'm facing some issues. Can you please check on this
https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7649/send-sol-from-pda-account-to-pubkey-in-anchor/7650#7650

Comment: someone was faster than me helping you :)